# Bootstrap, Thumbnail Carousel - Mouseover Sliding

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, slider, carousel

I want this Thumbnail Carousel Slider to slide when i hover the mouse over the next or previous item, or the invisible arrows. Also be able to grab the items and move them to the right and left. Of course the automatic sliding should stay where it is.

http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/thumbnail-carousel-single-image-sliding

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
    interval: 10000
})
$('.fdi-Carousel .item').each(function () {
    var next = $(this).next();
    if (!next.length) {
        next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }
    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

    if (next.next().length > 0) {
        next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    }
    else {
        $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    }
});
```

});

For better understanding here is the origin idea of what I imagine, how the function should slide:

http://codepen.io/johnblazek/full/nceyw

Is this possible in Bootstrap ?

Comment: not! You have to use some framework for this